# How to keep on adding multiple html links to a div(validationresults) on successful ajax call in which div is of type hidden

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Ajax function:

```
function paramvalidate(actionName) {
    var stressparams = $("#stressParam").val();
    var a=0;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : actionName,
        contentType : "text/plain",
        timeout : 900000,
        //processData: false, 
        //contentType: false, 
        data : stressparams,
        success : function(data) {
            alert("stressParams uploaded successfully");

            $(".validationresult").show();
        },
        error : function(error) {
            alert("Error:" + error);
        }
    });
 }
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="validationresult" hidden="">
  <a id="resultlink" href="http://localhost:8080/param/get.do" target="_blank">ValidationResults
  </a> //the hyperlink that is added for the first result     
// from the next results i want to add new html link for the same div or any alternate solution will be appreciated  
</div>
// I am evaluating the result in the
```

Validation results will be created after the first run like that I want to create validationResults2 validationResults3 and so on. Like this:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure or I understood your question correctly, but if you just want to keep adding the urls to the div use the following code in the success function:

```
$(".validationresult").append('<a id="result link" href="http://localhost:8080/param/get.do" target="_blank">ValidationResults</a>');
```

When the newest result should be on top use:

```
$(".validationresult").prepend('<a id="resultlink" href="http://localhost:8080/param/get.do" target="_blank">ValidationResults</a>');
```

Comment: i want to add the hyperlink that has come from the server response as as data(i.e   success : function(data) the data come from here)

Comment: Thats no problem, replace the link with: '<a id="resultlink" href="' + data + '">ValidationResults</a>' (Slightly different when you return an object you can use data.href for the link and data.text for the inner text such as: '<a id="resultlink" href="' + data.href + '">' + data.text + '</a>')

Comment: i am returning a string over there and i want it to be used as url over here

Comment: Than adjust the example above to your liking. Provide a better example if you need a more detailed answer. E.g. Show me the response of the server request from Ajax (the variable data in your case)

Comment: Its not working as you said please let me know if you have any other solutions

Comment: It will work, but provide me an example of the returned server data so I can give you the right code with the correct variable names

Comment: [link]("http://localhost:8080/stressparam/get"+"?hostip="+hostip+"&productname="+productname) this is the returned data by the server

Comment: Please, post it live. It's not there (corrupt link)

Comment: i just gave the context of the link BTW its not live

Comment: Please, just give back the returned server response. I can't figure out your structure with your reply